# Flutter: Cut widget edges according it's parents

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I made this widget :

```
Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ],
                ))
          ],
        ),
```

and this result is:

[image]

Now how can cut 4 square's edges according it's parent shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using [ClipOval](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html).

Wrap your grey container with it :

```
ClipOval(
    child:Container(
        //Your grey container
    ),
),
```